# Infinite loop in custom Spring Security application

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security, restful-authentication

We try to substitute an existing Spring Security Basic Login for a REST-API in an Open Source Application to achieve a custom login with a token. I read this blogpost about the topic: http://javattitude.com/2014/06/07/spring-security-custom-token-based-rest-authentication/

When the request has no header named "Cookie", I get correcty a 401 - unauthorized response (expected behaviour). When the request has a valid token, I get an infinite loop causing a `java.lang.StackOverflowError`:

```
    Exception in thread "http-bio-8080-exec-45" java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.NamesEnumerator.<init>(MimeHeaders.java:402)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.MimeHeaders.names(MimeHeaders.java:228)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getHeaderNames(Request.java:2108)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getHeaderNames(RequestFacade.java:726)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getHeaderNames(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:103)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getHeaderNames(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:103)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getHeaderNames(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:103)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getHeaderNames(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:103)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getHeaderNames(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:103)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getHeaderNames(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:103)
at org.activiti.rest.security.CustomTokenAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(CustomTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:43)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:211)
    at org.activiti.rest.security.CustomTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(CustomTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:86)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:65)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestWrapper$FirewalledRequestAwareRequestDispatcher.forward(RequestWrapper.java:132)
    at org.activiti.rest.security.TokenSimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess(TokenSimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler.java:30)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.successfulAuthentication(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.successfulAuthentication(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:298)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:235)
    at org.activiti.rest.security.CustomTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(CustomTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:86)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:65)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestWrapper$FirewalledRequestAwareRequestDispatcher.forward(RequestWrapper.java:132)
    at org.activiti.rest.security.TokenSimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess(TokenSimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler.java:30)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.successfulAuthentication(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.successfulAuthentication(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:298)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:235)
    at org.activiti.rest.security.CustomTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(CustomTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:86)
```

My Spring Security Configuration looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Bean
  public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    return new BasicAuthenticationProvider();
  }

  @Autowired
  AuthenticationProvider basicAuthenticationProvider;

  @Bean
  public CustomTokenAuthenticationFilter customTokenAuthenticationFilter(){
      System.out.println("+++ create new CustomTokenAuthenticationFilter for path=/**");
      return new CustomTokenAuthenticationFilter("/**");
  };

  @Autowired
  CustomTokenAuthenticationFilter customTokenAuthenticationFilter;

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      System.out.println("init of http security START");
     http
     .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
     .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
     .csrf().disable()
     .authorizeRequests()
       .anyRequest().authenticated()
     .and()//.authenticationProvider(basicAuthenticationProvider);
     .addFilterBefore(customTokenAuthenticationFilter,  BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
     .httpBasic();
       //.and().addFilter(filter);
    System.out.println("init of http security DONE");
  }
}
```

I already tried to change the URL-Mapping from `/**` to `/activiti-rest/**` but then, the Basic Authentication kicks in again.

This is my custom Token Authentication filter:

```
public class CustomTokenAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomTokenAuthenticationFilter.class);
    public CustomTokenAuthenticationFilter(String defaultFilterProcessesUrl) {
        super(defaultFilterProcessesUrl);
        super.setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher(defaultFilterProcessesUrl));
        setAuthenticationManager(new NoOpAuthenticationManager());
        setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new TokenSimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler());
    }


    public final String HEADER_SECURITY_TOKEN = "Cookie";//"LdapToken"; 


    /**
     * Attempt to authenticate request - basically just pass over to another method to authenticate request headers 
     */
    @Override public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
        Enumeration<String> headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
        int i = 0;
        while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()){
            String key = (String) headerNames.nextElement();
            String value = request.getHeader(key);
            System.out.println("+++ key["+i+"]" +key);
            System.out.println("+++ val["+i+"]" +value);
            i++;
        }
        String token = request.getHeader(HEADER_SECURITY_TOKEN);
        logger.info("token found:"+token);
        System.out.println("+++ token found:"+token);
        AbstractAuthenticationToken userAuthenticationToken = authUserByToken(token);
        if(userAuthenticationToken == null) throw new AuthenticationServiceException(MessageFormat.format("Error | {0}", "Bad Token"));
        System.out.println("+++ userAuthenticationToken:"+userAuthenticationToken.toString());
        return userAuthenticationToken;
    }


    /**
     * authenticate the user based on token
     * @return
     */
    private AbstractAuthenticationToken authUserByToken(String token) {
        if(token==null) {
            System.out.println("+++ i shouldn't be null +++");
            return null;
        }
        AbstractAuthenticationToken authToken = new JWTAuthenticationToken(token);
        try {
            return authToken;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            logger.error("Authenticate user by token error: ", e);
        }
        return authToken;
    }


    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ doFilter ");
        super.doFilter(req, res, chain);
    }
}
```

And my Custom Success handler. I think that this causes the infinite loop, but I cannot figure out, why:

```
public class TokenSimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    protected String determineTargetUrl(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {
        System.out.println("+++ yuhuuu determineTargetUrl+++");
        String context = request.getContextPath();
        String fullURL = request.getRequestURI();
        String url = fullURL.substring(fullURL.indexOf(context)+context.length());
        return url;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("+++ yuhuuu onAuthenticationSuccess+++");
        String url = determineTargetUrl(request,response);
        request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

All other classes (NoOpAuthenticationManager and RestAuthenticationEntryPoint) are exactly like in this blogpost.

Would be great I someone could give me a hint what could cause this infinite loop. As I said, it only occurs when the Request has a valid token.

Thanks and best regards
Ben

Comment: What happens if you remove the code that prints the headers?

Comment: I think the problem is the URL matching. I use /** as URL-Pattern. For example, I call the REST-URL localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service. My CustomFilter gets called because it matches /**. The request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response); has as url-parameter in this case /service, which also matches the URL-Pattern. So my CustomAuthenticationFilter gets called again. The loop occurs. But I have no idea how I could fix this since all REST-URLs should be protected.

Comment: If you are open to exploring an alternate approach, you can look at [this app](https://github.com/manish-in-java/spring-security-rest) which does away with custom filters and utilizes the core Spring Security infrastructure for securing REST API endpoints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your coding approach is valid. However, I can provide you with a slightly different but working approach. Before I start to explain the solution, here is the code:

### WebSecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().
    antMatchers("/restapi").hasRole("USER")
    .and().addFilterBefore(new SsoTokenAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class).httpBasic()
    .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
    // The order is important! During runtime Spring Security tries to find Provider-Implementations that
    // match the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken (which will be created later..). We must make sure
    // that daoAuthenticationProvider matches first. Why? Hard to explain, I figured it out with the debugger.
    auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
    auth.authenticationProvider(tokenAuthenticationProvider());

}

@Bean
public AuthenticationProvider tokenAuthenticationProvider() {
    return new SsoTokenAuthenticationProvider();
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
    // DaoAuthenticationProvider requires a userDetailsService object to be attached.
    // So we build one. This replaces the AuthenticationConfiguration, which is commented out below

    // Build the userDetailsService
    User userThatMustMatch = new User("michael", "password", AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList("ROLE_USER,ROLE_RESTUSER"));
    Collection<UserDetails> users = new ArrayList<>();
    users.add(userThatMustMatch);
    InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsService = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(users);  

    // Create the DaoAuthenticationProvider that will handle all HTTP BASIC AUTH requests
    DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    daoAuthProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    return daoAuthProvider;
}
```

### SsoTokenAuthenticationFilter.java

```
public class SsoTokenAuthenticationFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

public final String HEADER_SECURITY_COOKIE = "LdapToken"; 

private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
private AuthenticationDetailsSource<HttpServletRequest,?> ssoTokenAuthenticationDetailsSource = new SsoTokenWebAuthenticationDetailsSource();

public SsoTokenAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    // check if SSO token is available. If not, pass down to next filter in chain
    try {
        Cookie[] cookies = httpRequest.getCookies();
        if (cookies == null){
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }
        Cookie ssoCookie = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            if (cookies[i].getName().equals("ssoToken"))
                ssoCookie = cookies[i];
            }
        if (ssoCookie == null){
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        // SSO token found, now authenticate and afterwards pass down to next filter in chain
        authenticateWithSsoToken(httpRequest);
        logger.debug("now the AuthenticationFilter passes down to next filter in chain");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } catch (InternalAuthenticationServiceException internalAuthenticationServiceException) {
        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
        logger.error("Internal authentication service exception", internalAuthenticationServiceException);
        httpResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    } catch (AuthenticationException authenticationException) {
        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
        logger.debug("No or invalid SSO token");
        httpResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, authenticationException.getMessage());
    } 
}

private void authenticateWithSsoToken(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("+++ authenticateWithSSOToken +++");
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(null, null, AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList("ROLE_USER,ROLE_RESTUSER"));
    authRequest.setDetails(ssoTokenAuthenticationDetailsSource.buildDetails(request));        

    // Delegate authentication to SsoTokenAuthenticationProvider, he will call the SsoTokenAuthenticationProvider <-- because of the configuration in WebSecurityConfig.java
    Authentication authResult = authenticationManager.authenticate(authRequest);
}}
```

### SsoTokenAuthenticationProvider.java

```
public class SsoTokenAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

public SsoTokenAuthenticationProvider() {

}

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    SsoTokenWebAuthenticationDetails ssoTokenWebAuthenticationDetails = null;
    WebAuthenticationDetails webWebAuthenticationDetails = (WebAuthenticationDetails)authentication.getDetails();

    if (! (webWebAuthenticationDetails instanceof SsoTokenWebAuthenticationDetails)){
        // ++++++++++++++++++++++++
        // BASIC authentication....
        // ++++++++++++++++++++++++
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken emptyToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(null, null);
        emptyToken.setDetails(null);
        return emptyToken; //return null works, too.
    }

    // ++++++++++++++++++++++++
    // LDAP authentication....
    // ++++++++++++++++++++++++
    ssoTokenWebAuthenticationDetails = (SsoTokenWebAuthenticationDetails)webWebAuthenticationDetails;       
    Cookie ssoTokenCookie = ssoTokenWebAuthenticationDetails.getSsoTokenCookie();

    // check if SSO cookie is available
    if (ssoTokenCookie == null){ 
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(null, null); //do basic auth.
    }
    String username = ssoTokenCookie.getValue();

    // Do your SSO token authentication here
    if (! username.equals("michael"))
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(null, null); //do basic auth.

    // Create new Authentication object. Name and password can be null (but you can set the values of course).
    // Be careful with your role names!
    // In WebSecurityConfig the role "USER" is automatically prefixed with String "ROLE_", so it is "ROLE_USER" in the end.
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(null, null, AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList("ROLE_USER,ROLE_RESTUSER"));
    authRequest.setDetails(ssoTokenWebAuthenticationDetails);

    // Don't let spring decide.. you already have made the right decisions. Tell spring you have an authenticated user.
    // vielleicht ist dieses obere Kommentar auch bullshit... ich lese das morgen noch mal nach...
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    return authentication;
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
}
}
```

### SsoTokenWebAuthenticationDetailsSource.java

```
public class SsoTokenWebAuthenticationDetailsSource extends
    WebAuthenticationDetailsSource {

@Override
public WebAuthenticationDetails buildDetails(HttpServletRequest context) {
    return new SsoTokenWebAuthenticationDetails(context);
}

}
```

### SsoTokenWebAuthenticationDetails.java

```
public class SsoTokenWebAuthenticationDetails extends WebAuthenticationDetails {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1234567890L;

private Cookie ssoTokenCookie;

public SsoTokenWebAuthenticationDetails(HttpServletRequest request) {
    super(request);
    // Fetch cookie from request
    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();

    Cookie ssoTokenCookie = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        if (cookies[i].getName().equals("SSOToken"))
            ssoTokenCookie= cookies[i];
        }
    this.setSsoTokenCookie(ssoTokenCookie);
}

public Cookie getSsoTokenCookie() {
    return ssoTokenCookie;
}

public void setSsoTokenCookie(Cookie ssoTokenCookie) {
    this.ssoTokenCookie = ssoTokenCookie;
}
}
```

I describe the solution in a view words:

1. The Config class secures any `/restapi` controller with role `ROLE_USER`. The authentication can be done using httpBasic authentication, but before you can try basic auth. you must try to authenticate the user by a ssoTokenCookie (if available). Therefore, you set the `SsoTokenAuthenticationFilter` as filter before basic auth. is applied.
2. Inside the filter, you check if a ssoTokenCookie is available in request.

   - If yes, you delegate the authentication to the standard spring `AuthenticationManager`. The `AuthenticationManager` knows your own `SsoTokenAuthenticationProvider` implementation and delegates the authentication to it. Here, it is important to have the cookie information available. This can be done by use of a customized `WebAuthenticationDetails`.
   - if no, you pass down the work to the next filter in chain. It's no surprise, the standard `BasicAuthenticationFilter` will be called. Because you told Spring to use the standard `daoAuthenticationProvider` in `WebSecurityConfig.java`, Spring can authenticate the user when the proper credentials will be entered in the basic auth. dialog

Comment: Thank you very much. Worked great. In addition, I fixed my code with the following part: static final String FILTER_APPLIED = "__spring_security_scpf_applied";
if (req.getAttribute(FILTER_APPLIED) != null) {
     chain.doFilter(req, res);
     return;
    }
    req.setAttribute(FILTER_APPLIED, Boolean.TRUE);

With this, my recursion disappeared.