# In Spring Security 3.2.5, what is causing an infinite loop inside the AuthenticationManager implementation?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I had an interesting situation not long ago which caused an infinite loop (and eventually a stack overflow) in Spring Security's `AuthenticationManager`. For months, everything worked as expected, but then I decided to transfer my XML configuration to code-only configuration. Here was my basic setup in Java configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.my.company" })
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    // Disable default configuration
    public SecurityConfig() {
        super(true);
    }

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationProviderImpl authenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    MyAuthenticationEntryPoint customAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter authenticationTokenProcessingFilter;

    @Bean(name = "authenticationManager")
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {

        // Ignore requests of resources in security
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**")
        // Ignore requests to authentication
                .and().ignoring().antMatchers("/auth/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        // Define main authentication filter
        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenProcessingFilter,
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)

                // Request path authorization
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/**")
                .access("isAuthenticated()")

                // Authentication provider
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)

                // Security failure exception handling
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(customAuthenticationEntryPoint)

                // Session Management
                .and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)

                // Default security HTTP headers
                .and().headers().xssProtection().frameOptions()
                .cacheControl().contentTypeOptions();
    }
}
```

However, I soon found out that this configuration causes issues with my `AuthenticationProviderImpl` (which implements the Spring Security `AuthenticationProvider` interface). When the implementation's overridden `authenticate` method throws a `BadCredentialsException`, the exact same method in that class is called again perpetually until the stack overflows. The good news is that I fixed my configuration by simply overriding `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder)` in the `SecurityConfig` and declaring my implementation of the `AuthenticationProvider` there instead of in `configure(HttpSecurity http)`. Here is the fixed version:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.my.company" })
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    // Disable default configuration
    public SecurityConfig() {
        super(true);
    }

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationProviderImpl authenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    MyAuthenticationEntryPoint customAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter authenticationTokenProcessingFilter;

    @Bean(name = "authenticationManager")
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) {
        // Configure the authentication manager WITH the authentication
        // provider. Not overriding this method causes very bad things to
        // happen.
        builder.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {

        // Ignore requests of resources in security
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**")
        // Ignore requests to authentication
                .and().ignoring().antMatchers("/auth/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        // Define main authentication filter
        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenProcessingFilter,
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)

                // Request path authorization
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/**")
                .access("isAuthenticated()")
                .and()

                // Security failure exception handling
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(customAuthenticationEntryPoint)

                // Session Management
                .and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)

                // Default security HTTP headers
                .and().headers().xssProtection().frameOptions()
                .cacheControl().contentTypeOptions();
    }
}
```

Though I believe my problem is solved with the fixed configuration, I still have no idea why the application was infinitely calling `authenticate()` when an exception was thrown by my implementation of `AuthenticationProvider`? I tried stepping through and examining the Spring Security classes, but I was not finding a logical answer. Thanks ahead for your expertise!

Comment: At a guess, I'd say your class wasn't properly passing control onto the next link in the filter chain. I stress that this is pure speculation, but you may gain insight into what is going on, if you enable Spring Security's debug mode.

Comment: Interesting. The logging isn't showing much, except that this pattern repeats itself _after_ the first iteration: `2015-02-24 11:15:27 DEBUG - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'authenticationManager'
2015-02-24 11:15:27 DEBUG - Authentication attempt using com.my.company.service.AuthenticationProviderImpl`

Comment: In my case setting the `parentAuthenticationManager` property of `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` to be the the same instance as the default `AuthenticationManager` caused the issue. Whenever a `BadCredentialsException` was thrown an infinite loop would occur where a method from the `UserDetailsService` would be called over and over again. I think it happened because the `authenticate()` method of the default `AuthenticationManager` also calls the `authenticate()` method of the configured parent `AuthenticationManager`. If both instances are the same an infinite loop occurs.

Comment: This bug slipped into my code because i had copy pasted some `AuthenticationManager` configuration code from the answer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52243774/consider-defining-a-bean-of-type-org-springframework-security-authentication-au). This really shows that you shouldn't always simply copy-paste code without first checking what the code actually does ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few weeks ago I reproduced this behavior, too, [see this thread on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28368254/infinite-loop-in-custom-spring-security-application/28416952#28416952).

Dealing with the question I figured out that loops occur when the `AuthenticationManager` internally iterates through it's list of associated `AuthenticationProviders`, then finds a custom provider and tries to do the authentication using the provider that has been found. If the provider delegates the authentication back to the `AuthenticationManager` by calling `authenticate()`, you are in the loop. I guess your `AuthenticationProviderImpl` does something like that?

The order of your in the providers inside the `java.util.List` of the `AuthenticationManager` matters. The order is given by your configuration, e.g. by doing what you tried at first:

```
// Authentication provider
.and()
.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
```

By changing your configuration, you influenced the internally managed list of providers attached to your manager, which in the end will solve your code.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I looked at the Spring Security code, and see what you mean. I'm thinking now that _not_ defining my implementation of `AuthenticationProvider` with the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` caused a default `AuthenticationProvider` to be added to the filter chain as well. Thus, I guess they were just passing the ball back and forth to each other. By defining my implementation in the right `configure` method, I only added the one provider to the filter chain, which was correct in this case. This is exactly the answer I was hoping to get. Thanks!

Comment: But then what is the alternative? Thanks