# Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' in your configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I followed few suggestions mentioned here, but it didn't work for me. Hence, putting the question here

1. [How To Inject AuthenticationManager using Java Configuration in a Custom Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633555/how-to-inject-authenticationmanager-using-java-configuration-in-a-custom-filter/21639553#21639553)
2. [Spring required a bean of type 'AuthenticationManager'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49473634/spring-required-a-bean-of-type-authenticationmanager)

Could anyone please guide me what's the issue and how to fixed that ?

**Error:**

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field authenticationManager in com.techprimers.security.springsecurityauthserver.config.AuthorizationServerConfig required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' in your configuration.
```

**AuthorizationServerConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {

        security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients
                .inMemory()
                .withClient("ClientId")
                .secret("secret")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code")
                .scopes("user_info")
                .autoApprove(true);
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {

        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }
}
```

**ResourceServerConfig.java**

```
@EnableResourceServer
@Configuration
public class ResourceServerConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .permitAll();
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
    }
}
```

The code reference taken from https://github.com/TechPrimers/spring-security-oauth-mysql-example, only updated Spring Boot Parent Version to `2.0.4.RELEASE`, things started breaking.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

It seems like it's one of the "breaking changes" Spring Boot 2.0 introduced. I believe that your case is described in [Spring Boot 2.0 Migration Guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#authenticationmanager-bean).

In your `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class you need to override `authenticationManagerBean` method and annotate it with `@Bean`, i.e.:

```
@Override
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
```

Comment: **Please remove the** `.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean())` **part from the example because it causes an error!** I just found out that this was the cause of an infinite recursion which eventually leads to a `StackOverflowException`. The infinite recursion happens whenever `AuthenticationManager.authenticate()` is called with an incorrect password. This throws `BadCredentialsException` which causes the same method to be called again for some reason. This most likely happens because the `parentAuthenticationManager` and the `AuthenticationManager` are the same instance.

Comment: @Maurice thank you for your comment. I admit the second part of my answer was a bit unfortunate and not really necessary. I removed it.

Comment: Note: In Spring Security 5.x, `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`  is `@Deprecated` in favor of `WebSecurityCustomizer` and/or `SecurityFilterChain`.

Answer (score 14):

### Deprecated "WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter"

As `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` it has been deprecated, you can now use:

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class)
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just add this to the AuthenticationManagerBuilder

```java
@Override
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
```

And in your controller where you need to use it add this :

```java
@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider to register a `GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter` to configure the `AuthenticationManager`

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
        final List<GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter> configurers = new ArrayList<>();
        configurers.add(new GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
                        // auth.doSomething()
                    }
                }
        );
        return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

}
```

where I assumed for instance that you want to register a custom `UserDetailsService` (i.e. `MyUserDetailsService`) and a custom password encoder (`MyPasswordEncoder`).

Answer (score 0):

I forget to write "@Component" at the top of the class.
For Example:

```
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CustomAuthenticationManager implements AuthenticationManager {
```

Answer (score -2):

You may execute following command:
"mvn clean package" and then restart the application

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails' in your configuration.