# Required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' that could not be found. message from spring security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to implement one sample demo for Spring Security with Spring Boot for checking the authentication. I am trying to implement a basic workout for Spring Security and getting the following message,

```
Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.spacestudy.service.CustomAuthenticationProvider required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint' in your configuration.
```

My security config class SecurityConfig.java,

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private AuthenticationEntryPoint authEntryPoint;

 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .addFilter(new ApplicationContextHeaderFilter((ApplicationContext) authenticationManager()));
    }
}
```

And my BasicAuthenticationFilter implementation like the following,

```
@Component
public class  CustomAuthenticationProvider  extends  BasicAuthenticationFilter    { 

public CustomAuthenticationProvider(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    super(authenticationManager);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = getAuthentication(request);
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
   String bearerToken = request.getHeader("accessToken");
String username = "test";
String password = "test";
    if (username != null && !username.isEmpty()) {
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, null, null);
      }
    return null;
    }
 }
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52243774/consider-defining-a-bean-of-type-org-springframework-security-authentication-au/52244758

Answer (score 2):

You can try on this, put it in config security file

```
 @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
        return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Lot of problems are there in your code.

1. `(ApplicationContext) authenticationManager()`
   you can not cast AuthenticationManager to ApplicationContext
2. `.addFilter(new ApplicationContextHeaderFilter(...))`
    
   I  don't know Why you are using `ApplicationContextHeaderFilter` for simple demo application.

   - You should have preferred `BasicAuthenticationFilter` or even simple default configuration provided for `HttpSecurity` with `.httpBasic()`
   - You should have preferred `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` or even simple default configuration provided in `HttpSecurity` with `.formLogin()`
3. `CustomAuthenticationProvider  extends  BasicAuthenticationFilter`
   An authentication provider is one which implements `AuthenticationProvider` interface. In your case naming should be `xxxAuthFilter`.
4. You have done nothing in below code.(got existing authentication object and set it back without creating an valid authentication object.)

```
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = getAuthentication(request);
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

---

Coming to the AuthenticationManager and AuthFilters implementation point of view,
For add filter you can add any implementation of Spring Security provided filters as given below
.addFilter([AnyFilterImplementationFromThisLink](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#addFilter-javax.servlet.Filter-))
(But not all filters are auth filters. Where auth filters will attempt to authenticate with the authenticationManager configured)
For example If you consider `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` or `BasicAuthenticationFilter`

> you should take care of setting `AuthenticationManager` where your auth manager should override `authenticate()` method and it should return `Authentication` object(where `Authentication` object will have auth principal, credentials and granted authorities list)

Or

> If you don't want to implement authentication manager...
> In simple way in your filters(implementation of OncePerRequestFilter) doFilterInternal() method set the `Authentication` object in `SecurityContext`
>
> ```java
> List<GrantedAuthority> authorityList = new ArrayList<>();
> GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER");
> authorityList.add(authority);
> UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password, authorityList);
> //Note UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken implements Authentication
> SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
> ```

How any auth filter works is if there is a valid `Authentication` object then filter chain will continue without attempting authentication otherwise it will `attemptAuthentication` by overrided `attemptAuthentication()` method.
 
But your `ApplicationContextHeaderFilter` is a implementation of `OncePerRequestFilter` where it has no `attemptAuthentication()` and i  don't know the order of `ApplicationContextHeaderFilter` if it's order is after creating security context then you can set the authentication object to security context.

Answer (score 0):

Your error seems to be that the `AuthenticationManager` is not present as a Spring Bean.

## Option 1

Register an `AuthenticationManager` in Spring Bean. All is provided by Spring for do this directly in your `SecurityConfig` class by overriding the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter#authenticationManagerBean` method like explain in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html#authenticationManagerBean--) of it

```
@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
```

## Option 2

Avoid to register an `AuthenticationManager` in Spring, but directly your `CustomAuthenticationProvider` classs.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public CustomAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() throws Exception {
        return new CustomAuthenticationProvider(authenticationManager());
    }
}
```

Don't forget to remove the `@Component` annotation on the `CustomAuthenticationProvider` class with this method.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but shoudn't the `CustomAuthenticationProvider implement AuthenticationProvider` and `AuthenticationManager` is just a container for authentication providers and it seems that you dont have any.

Check this site for more info
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-provider

Answer (score 0):

Create a new java class. And Configure like below:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception{
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```