# Update the Spring Security configuration class with Spring Boot 2.7.3

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

Right now I am using a Spring Security configuration which allows me the following operations:

1. The user can save their login credentials in the browser. When the user returns to the site, he does not have to re-enter the name and password. To register, the user only puts a name and password, not an email. The user can also decide not to save the password in the browser.
2. When the user changes his name he does not have to log in again using the new name. The user remains connected indefinitely with the new name. The user avoids logging in after the name change.
3. When the user changes his password he does not have to log in again using the new password. The user remains connected indefinitely with the new password. The user avoids logging in after password change.

All good and all great but with one problem: WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is a deprecated class!

I have updated all my code in the following way (I am not rewriting the previous code because it is not useful). I can recreate point 1 but not point 2 and point 3. **I can't figure out how to use these filters.**

**CustomFilter.java**

```java
    public class CustomFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {
        static final String FILTER_REQUEST_MATCHER = "/some-endpoint";
        public CustomFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
            super(FILTER_REQUEST_MATCHER, authenticationManager);
        }
        @Override
        public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
            String user = request.getParameter("username");
            String password = request.getParameter("password");
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authReq = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, password);
            return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authReq);
        }
    
    }
```

**MyCustomDsl.java**

```java
    public class MyCustomDsl extends AbstractHttpConfigurer<MyCustomDsl, HttpSecurity> {
        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManager.class);
            http.addFilterBefore(new CustomFilter(authenticationManager), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        }
        public static MyCustomDsl customDsl() {
            return new MyCustomDsl();
        }
    }
```

**GestioneUtentiSpringSecurity.java**

```java
    @Service
    public class GestioneUtentiSpringSecurity implements UserDetailsService {
        @Autowired
        private UtenteRepository utenteRepository;
        @Autowired
        private RuoloRepository ruoloRepository;
        @Autowired
        EseguiVariabiliDiSistema eseguiVariabiliDiSistema;
        @Autowired
        LivelliDeiRuoli livelliDeiRuoli;
        @Override
        public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String nomeUtente) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
            Utente utente = trovaUtenteConPrivilegiDiAutenticazione(nomeUtente);
            if (utente == null) {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("L'utente " + nomeUtente + " non è stato trovato nel database.");
            }
            List<String> ruoliUtente = null;
            try {
                ruoliUtente = this.ruoloRepository.trovaRuoliUtente(utente.getId());
            }catch (Exception b){
                ruoliUtente = null;
            }
            List<GrantedAuthority> grantList = null;
            try{
                grantList = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
                if (ruoliUtente != null) {
                    for (String ruolo : ruoliUtente) {
                        GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(ruolo);
                        grantList.add(authority);
                    }
                }
            }catch (Exception c){
                grantList = null;
            }
            UserDetails userDetails = null;
            if((utente != null) && (ruoliUtente != null) && (grantList != null)){
                userDetails = (UserDetails) new User(utente.getNome(), utente.getPassword(), grantList);
            }
            return userDetails;
        }
        public Utente trovaUtenteConPrivilegiDiAutenticazione(String nomeUtente){
            try{
                Utente utente = utenteRepository.trovaUtente(nomeUtente);
                if(livelliDeiRuoli.requisitiUtenteConRuoloMassimo(utente)){
                    return utente;
                } else{
                    eseguiVariabiliDiSistema.trovaVariabileSenzaVerificaUtente(
                            new VariabileSistema(0L, "login", "")
                    );
                    if(eseguiVariabiliDiSistema.getVariabileDiSistema().getValore().equals("true")){
                        return utente;
                    }else if(eseguiVariabiliDiSistema.getVariabileDiSistema().getValore().equals("false")){
                        return null;
                    }else{
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                return null;
            }
        }
    
    }
```

**SecurityConfiguration.java**

```java
    @Configuration
    public class SecurityConfiguration {
        @Autowired
        LivelliDeiRuoli livelliDeiRuoli;
        @Autowired
        GestioneUtentiSpringSecurity gestioneUtentiSpringSecurity;
        @Autowired
        private DataSource dataSource;
        @Bean
        public PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository() {
            JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl db = new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl();
            db.setDataSource(dataSource);
            return db;
        }
        @Bean
        public static BCryptPasswordEncoder metodoCrittografia() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }
        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
            http.authorizeRequests().and()
                    .rememberMe().tokenRepository(this.persistentTokenRepository())
                    .tokenValiditySeconds(365 * 24 * 60 * 60);
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(
                    "/",
                    "/login",
                    "/benvenuto",
                    "/registrazione",
                    "/registrazione-eseguita",
                    "/cookie",
                    "/contatti",
                    "logout"
            ).permitAll();
            // ...
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/cambio-password")
                    .access("hasAnyRole('" + livelliDeiRuoli.elencoRuoli(1L) + "')");
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/cambio-nome")
                    .access("hasAnyRole('" + livelliDeiRuoli.elencoRuoli(1L) + "')");
            // ...
            http.authorizeRequests().and().formLogin()
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/pagina-login")
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                    .failureUrl("/login?errore=true")
                    .usernameParameter("username")
                    .passwordParameter("password")
                    .and().logout().logoutUrl("/pagina-logout")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout=true");
            // ...
            http.apply(customDsl());
            return http.build();
        }
    
    }
```

**cambio-password.html**

```html
        <form th:action="@{/cambio-password}" th:object="${CambioPassword}" method="POST" id="cambioPassword">
            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 m-0 p-2">
                    <p>Vecchia password:</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 m-0 p-2">
                    <input type="password" th:field="*{vecchiaPassword}" placeholder="Vecchia password."
                           id="vecchiaPassword" autofocus class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 m-0 p-2 testo_rosso">
                    <span th:if="${ErroreVecchiaPassword != null}" th:utext="${ErroreVecchiaPassword}">..</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 m-0 p-2">
                    <p>Nuova password:</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 m-0 p-2">
                    <input type="password" th:field="*{passwordForm}" placeholder="Nuova password."
                           id="passwordForm" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 m-0 p-2 testo_rosso">
                    <span th:if="${ErrorePasswordForm != null}" th:utext="${ErrorePasswordForm}">..</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 m-0 p-2">
                    <p>Conferma nuova password:</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 m-0 p-2">
                    <input type="password" th:field="*{confermaPasswordForm}" placeholder="Conferma password."
                           id="confermaPasswordForm" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 m-0 p-2 testo_rosso">
                    <span th:if="${ErroreConfermaPasswordForm != null}" th:utext="${ErroreConfermaPasswordForm}">..
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 m-0 p-2">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 m-0 p-2">
                    <input type="submit" value="Invia" class="btn btn-primary">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 m-0 p-2">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

**cambio-nome.html**

```html
        <form th:action="@{/cambio-nome}" th:object="${CambioNome}" method="POST" id="cambioNome">
            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 m-0 p-2">
                    <p>Nuovo nome:</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 m-0 p-2">
                    <input type="text" th:field="*{nuovoNome}" placeholder="Nuovo nome" id="nuovoNome" autofocus
                           class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 m-0 p-2 testo_rosso">
                    <span th:if="${ErroreNome != null}" th:utext="${ErroreNome}">..</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 m-0 p-2">
                    <p>Password:</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 m-0 p-2">
                    <input type="password" th:field="*{password}" placeholder="Password" id="password"
                           class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 m-0 p-2 testo_rosso">
                    <span th:if="${ErrorePassword != null}" th:utext="${ErrorePassword}">..</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 m-0 p-2">
                    <p>Conferma password:</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 m-0 p-2">
                    <input type="password" th:field="*{confermaPassword}" placeholder="Conferma password"
                           id="confermaPassword" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 m-0 p-2 testo_rosso">
                    <span th:if="${ErroreConfermaPassword != null}" th:utext="${ErroreConfermaPassword}">..</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 m-0 p-2">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 m-0 p-2">
                    <input type="submit" value="Invia" class="btn btn-primary">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 m-0 p-2 testo_rosso">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

**login.html**

```html
            <form name="form" th:action="@{/pagina-login}" method="POST" id="formLogin">
                <input type = "hidden" name = "${_csrf.parameterName}" value = "${_csrf.token}">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 m-0 p-2">
                        <h3>Inserisci il nome utente e la password:</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 m-0 p-2">
                        <label for="nomeUtente" class="col-form-label">Nome utente:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 m-0 p-2">
                        <input type="text" name="username" id="nomeUtente" placeholder="Nome utente" autofocus
                               class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 m-0 p-2">
                        <label for="password" class="col-form-label">Password:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 m-0 p-2">
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password"
                               class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 m-0 p-2">
                        <!--/* Vuoto */-->
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 m-0 p-2">
                        <input class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" type="submit" value="Invia">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 m-0 p-2">
                        <label class="col-form-label">Salva la password: </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 m-0 p-2">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember-me" class="form-check-input">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

**Deepening:**
*(Below is the old code that I can't rewrite.)*

With the old version of Spring Boot I added a very convenient login() method to the class marked with the *@Controller* annotation.
I could log in as and when I wanted. I would like to know what I should use instead of login().

```java
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authManager;

    public void login(HttpServletRequest req, String user, String pass) {
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authReq = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, pass);
        Authentication auth = authManager.authenticate(authReq);
        SecurityContext sc = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        sc.setAuthentication(auth);
    }

    // code I entered to login (after the name or password change)
    // what should I put in place of this method with the new version of spring?
    // can you give an example?
    login(request,user,password);
```

Comment: 1. Read the documentation which tells you what to change. 2. intellij doesn't know all your configuration, ignore it (or remove the field and change `persistentToekRepository` to `persistentTokenRepository(DataSource datasource)` and remove the autowired field.

Comment: Thanks for your intervention. I have updated the class but I don't know how to set the "remember me button" on Spring Security. Is the change I made correct? How do I update the code for this feature? With the old code, the "remember me button" worked even when the user changed their password!

Comment: Your configuration is wrong, the `authorizeRequest().anyRequest()` **must** be last. The order in which you define filters is also the order in which they are consulted, so withyour current config all your other `authorizeRequest()` calls are not working. What isn't working? The config ( I don't get the `authorizeRequests().and()` as that is pretty useless), compilation error, or ???

Comment: Thank you very much for your first invaluable contribution. I have fixed the second code but I am still having problems.
The codes 1, 2, 3 and 4 (you can find these numbers in the comments) I added them to configure the tag "remember my password" in login.html (<input type = "checkbox" name = "remember-me" class = "form-check-input">).

Comment: In the past, when the user changed their password, Spring Boot forgot the password. The user was forced to log in again and re-tick the input tag described above. I added code 3 to fix that problem. With the code 3 Spring Boot also remembered the password of the users who had changed the password. Without code 3, after the password was changed, the user had to log in again and remind the WebApp to save the password for subsequent accesses.
With codes 1, 2, 3 and 4 I get a compile error (see the main post).
Without the codes 1, 2, 3 and 4 I get a WebApp startup error (see the main post).

Comment: I highly doubt 1 is leading to a compilation error. On 3 remove the `@Override` annotaiton you aren't extending anything so you aren't overriding anything either.

Comment: You probably don't need to use the `authenticationManagerBean()` method in your configuration. Unless you are using it somewhere else in your code.

Comment: The "authenticationManagerBean()" method is marked in red, it is not found. To be able to compile I have to remove code 3. I don't use "authenticationManagerBean()" but code 3 was used in the past to keep the user who decided to change their password authenticated.

Comment: "private DataSource dataSource" is not marked in red and does not generate a compile error but it is underlined in red by IntelliJ. The error message on "dataSource" is as follows:
Could not autowire. No beans of 'DataSource' type found.
 Inspection info:
Reports autowiring problems on injection points of Spring beans:
More than one bean of 'concrete' type
No beans of 'concrete' type
No bean with qualifier
Autowired method or constructor without parameters
Example:
public interface FooInterface {...}
etc...

Comment: If I remove code 3 and leave code 1, 2 and 4 I get the boot error described above:
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
etc ...

Comment: However, I would like to make a clarification. I am not fond of any code. I need a basic Spring Security configuration to: A) monitor access to pages B) enable csrf C) create a persistent 1 year login. Obviously with the modern code of Spring Boot 2.7.0.

Comment: I would gladly update my webapp if I was told how to do it. I can't invent anything. A framework without documentation is useless.

Comment: Someone voted my discussion negatively saying it was unclear but I answered all the questions, clarifying the difficulties and problems. It would be more honest for the user who voted negatively on this thread to admit that he is unable to respond.

Comment: I read these 2 pages and tried the codes but I don't solve:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52243774/consider-defining-a-bean-of-type-org-springframework-security-authentication-au
https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring-boot/fix-websecurityconfigureradapter-deprecated

Comment: The method `crittografiaPassword` is not needed. Since the `userDetailsService` and `passwordEncoder` are beans they will automatically be picked up by Spring Security. You get an error that there is no `AuthenticationManager` bean, because you are trying to autowire a bean that does not exist. Based on the error message, you are autowiring it in `ControlloPagineWeb`. Please share that class and how you are using the `AuthenticationManager`. This code can likely be moved into a custom DSL as described in the blog post that you linked.

Comment: Thanks Eleftheria Stein-Kousathana, I am delighted to read your help. I have tried many codes for this damn AuthenticationManager but I always see red ferrari codes. I have deleted password encryption from the class.

Comment: Is it possible to show this 3 month discussion to the Spring Security programmers? The curiosity to know the solution, after all this time, is very high.

Comment: No solution, what a desolation.

Comment: What is the point of producing all these versions of the software if assistance is lacking and the developers cannot use the product?
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/community.html
https://spring.io/blog/2019/02/06/legacy-forums-will-be-shutdown-february-28
https://stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 4):

I agree that this is poorly documented. This is how you can put a reference to org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager into the Spring Application context and inject it/autowire it wherever you wish:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {
...
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
        return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution. If I change the name the user loses all roles. I need to log in again. Perhaps the only way is to use CustomFilter but the code to be written is not clear.

Comment: I added a piece of code to the post, please re-read.

Answer (score 0):

Since many of the questions have been answered in the comments I will focus on the `AuthenticationManager` bean not being found in the Controller.

The recommended approach is to move the authentication logic into a filter, instead of having it in the Controller.

First, you can define a custom filter that processes the authentication. It will look similar to the [`UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/5.7.x/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java) that Spring Security provides.

Below is a skeleton example:

```java
public class CustomFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {
    // execute this filter when it matches this endpoint
    static final String FILTER_REQUEST_MATCHER = "/some-endpoint"; 

    public CustomFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super(FILTER_REQUEST_MATCHER, authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        String user = obtainUsername(request);
        String password = obtainPassword(request);
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authReq = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, pass);
        return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authReq);
    }
}
```

You can then create a custom DSL that obtains the `AuthenticationManager` and adds the `CustomFilter`:

```java
public class MyCustomDsl extends AbstractHttpConfigurer<MyCustomDsl, HttpSecurity> {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = 
                http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManager.class);
        http.addFilterBefore(new CustomFilter(authenticationManager), 
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }

    public static MyCustomDsl customDsl() {
        return new MyCustomDsl();
    }
}
```

The custom DSL can then be applied when building the `SecurityFilterChain`:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // ...
    http.apply(customDsl());
    return http.build();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I am very close to the solution thanks to your wonderful help.
I have added the "eseguiRegistrazione()" method and the "GestioneUtentiSpringSecurity.java" class to my post so my approach is clearer.
I make a premise, I don't use json and my application is not a REST application.
The only thing I don't understand is how to enter the username and password in the filter. I don't know how to write obtainUsername(), obtainPassword(). I took these 2 parameters directly from the form with the object "@ModelAttribute("Registrazione") Registrazione datiInseriri".

Comment: @FedericoGalimberti Have you tried calling `request.getParameter(x)`?

Comment: Of course, that's the first thing I did but I don't know what to write in place of the letter x.

Comment: What are the fields in the form that is being submitted? Another option is to see all the available parameters by checking the value of `request.getParameterMap();`

Comment: Thanks for the tips. To answer your first question, if I understand what you are asking correctly, I added the html form tag to the first post.
I tried to write the following codes and I no longer see red writing.
'String user = request.getParameter("username");'
'String password = request.getParameter("password");'
There remains a line of code that blocks the compilation which is the following:
'return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authReq);'

Comment: This is the error:
java: it.applicazionijava.gestioneutenti.autenticazione_spring_security.CustomFilter is not abstract and does not override abstract method attemptAuthentication(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) in org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter

Comment: How do you highlight the code in gray?

Comment: Ok, I solved. The following code is compiled:
    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        String user = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authReq = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, password);
        return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authReq);
    }

Comment: In the controller what do I write in place of this?
                    login(
                            request,
                            eseguiRegistrazione.getUtenteRegistrato().getNome(),
                            datiInseriri.getPasswordForm()
                    );

Comment: If I remore login() I get this error:


***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in it.applicazionijava.gestioneutenti.autenticazione_spring_security.CustomFilter required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Where is that error coming from? Do you have an annotation like `@Component` or something else on `CustomFilter`?

Comment: Thanks, you were right, great! I had forgotten one @Component code too many after some corrections of mine. Now my application starts if I remove the login() method and the authManager variable from ControlloPagineWeb. Can you explain to me how I should rewrite login() with the new approach?
The login() method is required. For example, thanks to login() the user does not have to re-enter the password after registering or after changing his name or password. I just can't delete login() from my project.
Maybe I am one step away from the conclusion.

Comment: The project compiles but the IDE claims these codes are incorrect.
'''@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;'''
 -> '''Could not autowire. No beans of 'DataSource' type found.'''
'''@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {'''
 -> '''Could not autowire. No beans of 'HttpSecurity' type found. '''

Comment: The logic from `login()` should all be moved to the filter. The IDE is not aware of every configuration, you can ignore the warnings of type "could not autowire".

Comment: Ok, thanks, I can add this code in "CustomFilter":
"public Authentication login(String nome, String password) {
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authReq = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(nome, password);
        return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authReq);
    }"
The remaining problem is how to capture the method in "ControlloPagineWeb". If I declare "CustomFilter" as @Servlet the project is not compiled. (P.S .: How do you gray out the codes in the comments?)

Comment: The filter will be executed before the request reaches the Controller. The logic should all be moved out of the Controller and into the filter. You can read more about filters in the Spring Security [reference docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/architecture.html#servlet-filters-review).

Comment: Thanks so much for your support. I have updated the ControlloPagineWeb class with the 3 methods to be updated. I have no idea how to move the logic into CustomFilter. I use a servlet to verify that the data entered is correct. The servlet writes data to the db if they are acceptable. If the modification of the db has taken place executeRegistration.getUserRegistered() is not empty. Can't I simulate a login()? I just don't know how to deal with this doFilter(). I hope you can solve this problem, I want to check your code solved but I still have to solve this problem.

Comment: UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authReq = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            eseguiRegistrazione.getUtenteRegistrato().getNome(),
                            datiInseriri.getPasswordForm()
                    );

Comment: public void doFilter(
            ServletRequest request,
            ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain,
            String nome,
            String password
    ) throws ServletException,
            IOException {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        login(nome, password);
    }

    public Authentication login(String nome, String password) {
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authReq = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(nome, password);
        return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authReq);
    }

Comment: I don't know how to invoke the filter from other classes. Also I should pass to the filter of the parameters chosen by me not taken from a form. What you write is complicated. I can't make up these steps.

Comment: You should not call the filter from other classes. The filter gets invoked automatically by Spring Security on an incoming request. I'll like the [reference docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/architecture.html#servlet-filters-review) again where you can see a visual representation.

Comment: So how do I re-authenticate the user who changed the password?

Comment: I have added the 'doFilter()' method to my previous post as you never recommended but it doesn't work. Can you explain to me how to rebuild the autologin?
Should I put the html tags 'name' in 'doFilter ()'?
How do I behave in the event of a password change? When the user changes his password he does not re-enter his name. In the html page I get the name using '# request.userPrincipal.name'.

Comment: Is it possible to show this 3 month discussion to the Spring Security programmers? The curiosity to know the solution, after all this time, is very high.

Comment: I added a piece of code to the post, please re-read.

Comment: No solution, what a desolation.

Comment: What is the point of producing all these versions of the software if assistance is lacking and the developers cannot use the product?
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/community.html
https://spring.io/blog/2019/02/06/legacy-forums-will-be-shutdown-february-28
https://stackoverflow.com/