# Action: Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' in your configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot

`I followed few suggestions mentioned here, but it didn't work for me. Hence, putting the question here

How To Inject AuthenticationManager using Java Configuration in a Custom Filter
Spring required a bean of type 'AuthenticationManager'
Could anyone please guide me what's the issue and how to fixed that ?`

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 2 of constructor in com.minul.springjwt.auth.AuthenticationService required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' in your configuration.
```

```
package com.minul.springjwt.auth;

import com.minul.springjwt.config.JwtService;
import com.minul.springjwt.user.Role;
import com.minul.springjwt.user.User;
import com.minul.springjwt.user.UserRepository;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthenticationService {

    private final UserRepository repository;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private JwtService jwtService;

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;



    public AuthenticationResponse register(RegisterRequest request) {
        var user = User.builder()
                .firstname(request.getFirstname())
                .lastname(request.getLastname())
                .email(request.getEmail())
                .password(passwordEncoder.encode(request.getPassword()))
                .role(Role.USER)
                .build();
        repository.save(user);
        var jwtToken = jwtService.genarateToken(user);
        return  AuthenticationResponse.builder()
                .token(jwtToken)
                .build();
    }


    public AuthenticationResponse authenticate(AuthenticationRequest request) {
        authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        request.getEmail(),
                        request.getPassword()
                )
        );
        var user = repository.findByEmail(request.getEmail())
                .orElseThrow();
        var jwtToken = jwtService.genarateToken(user);
        return  AuthenticationResponse.builder()
                .token(jwtToken)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The injection doesn't seem to be the problem here, rather the `AuthenticationManager` bean itself.

In your case it is missing, since Spring Boot 2.0 you need to expose it yourself by overriding the `authenticationManagerBean`-method in your `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`-class:

```
@Override
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
```

It's also described in the [Spring Boot 2.0. migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#authenticationmanager-bean) and a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52243774/consider-defining-a-bean-of-type-org-springframework-security-authentication-au).

If you use a later version than Spring Security 5.7.0 you'll have a slightly different approach as the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` has been deprecated and replaced by component based security configuration:

```
@Bean
AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(
        AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
    return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
}
```

(see [How to replace deprecated WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter in Spring Security 5.7.x](https://backendstory.com/spring-security-how-to-replace-websecurityconfigureradapter/))