# Infinite loop when authenticating user: Implementation of JWT with Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jwt

**EDIT: I am now getting a 403 forbidden, access denied on all requests besides register and login**

I am testing out my endpoints for an application after having implemented JWT authentication and spring security based on this article: https://medium.com/@hantsy/protect-rest-apis-with-spring-security-and-jwt-5fbc90305cc5

Similarly, my other sources of inspiration include: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X80nJ5T7YpE

Registration and login of a user are functional, but when I perform subsequent requests requiring the JWT in the header, I get an infinite loop/recursion and a stack overflow error. However, when I input a non-existing JWT on purpose, it throws back the appropriate error message and works well. So the problem is with successfully authenticating a valid JWT. After looking online at different stack overflow answers such as: 
[Infinite loop in custom Spring Security application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28368254/infinite-loop-in-custom-spring-security-application)
[Infinite loop in custom Spring Security application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28368254/infinite-loop-in-custom-spring-security-application/28416952#28416952)
[In Spring Security 3.2.5, what is causing an infinite loop inside the AuthenticationManager implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28686745/in-spring-security-3-2-5-what-is-causing-an-infinite-loop-inside-the-authentica)

They all seem to say the same thing which is that the ProviderManager class is looking through the list of auth providers to find one that can authenticate the given authentication and it is not finding one , which causes this error, and they suggest to implement your own authentication provider. Below is my code for the different relevant classes. Note that I do not use a userDetailsService class; instead I have my own UserService class which has basically the functionality of userDetailsService traditionally and also application-specific code. I also did not implement my own authentication provider, following the code examples I mentioned above, so I would like to avoid implementing the authentication providers since the code samples mentioned work and are simpler.

**JwtProvider class**

```
@Component
public class JwtProvider {
    @Value("${security.jwt.token.secret-key:secret}")
    private String secretKey = "secret";

    @Value("${security.jwt.token.expire-length:3600000}")
    private long validityInMilliseconds = 3600000; // 1h

    @Autowired
    private AppUserService appUserService;

    // encoding the secret used to create the signature for the JWT
    @PostConstruct
    protected void init() {
        secretKey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(secretKey.getBytes());
    }

    public String createToken(String userEmail) {
        Claims claims = Jwts.claims().setSubject(userEmail); // subject is the person who is being authenticated
        Date now = new Date();
        Date validity = new Date(now.getTime() + validityInMilliseconds);
        return Jwts.builder()//
                .setClaims(claims)//
                .setIssuedAt(now)//
                .setExpiration(validity)//
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, secretKey)//
                .compact();
    }

    public Authentication getAuthentication(String token) {
        AppUser user = this.appUserService.getAppUserByEmail(getUserEmail(token));
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, "");
    }

    // get userEmail in the jwt token that we receive
    public String getUserEmail(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secretKey).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody().getSubject();
    }

    // validate a token that we have: not expired, and matches the userEmail
    public boolean validateToken(String token) {
        try {
            Jws<Claims> claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secretKey).parseClaimsJws(token);
            if (claims.getBody().getExpiration().before(new Date())) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        } catch (JwtException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

**JwtConfigurer class**

```
package ca.mcgill.ecse321.petadoption.controller;

import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.SecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

// configures how we filter http requests
// specifies order of applying filters
public class JwtConfigurer extends SecurityConfigurerAdapter<DefaultSecurityFilterChain, HttpSecurity> {
    private JwtProvider jwtProvider;
    public JwtConfigurer(JwtProvider jwtProvider) {
        this.jwtProvider = jwtProvider;
    }
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        JwtFilter customFilter = new JwtFilter(jwtProvider);
        http.addFilterBefore(customFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class); 
    }
}
```

**JwtFilter class**

```
// Job: intercept a request and look at the header to get the JWT
public class JwtFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
    private JwtProvider jwtProvider;

    public JwtFilter(JwtProvider jwtProvider) {
        this.jwtProvider = jwtProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain filterChain) 
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        String token = resolveToken((HttpServletRequest) req);
            if (token != null && jwtProvider.validateToken(token)) { // if token is not null and it isn't expired and it is valid 
                Authentication auth = jwtProvider.getAuthentication(token); // returning the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth); 
            }
        filterChain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    public String resolveToken(HttpServletRequest req) {
        String bearerToken = req.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (bearerToken != null && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return bearerToken.substring(7, bearerToken.length());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**SecurityConfigurer class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    JwtProvider jwtProvider;

    @Autowired
    AppUserService appUserService;

    // this is because we cannot perform @autowired authManager anymore cuz its only compatible w/ older Spring Boot
    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .csrf().disable() // this disables cross-site request forgery where an attacker manages to get an authenticated user to perform a malicious request to his liking using diff links and such
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS) // tell it to use the filterChain that intercepts requests and checks the authorization header for a jwt
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/register/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .apply(new JwtConfigurer(jwtProvider)); // this specifies to add our custom filter before the usernamepasswordauthenticationfilter
    }

}
```

Here is the error I get:

```
  2020-03-14 12:14:27.183 ERROR 784 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy120.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:195) ~[spring-security-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:501) ~[spring-security-config-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor107.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy120.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:195) ~[spring-security-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:501) ~[spring-security-config-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor107.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy120.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:195) ~[spring-security-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:501) ~[spring-security-config-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor107.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy120.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:195) ~[spring-security-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:501) ~[spring-security-config-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor107.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
```

I am relatively new to Spring and Spring Boot so any help is appreciated thank you

Comment: Did you ever get a fix for this?

Comment: This is relevant. 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/11088